# Is it trivial that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Is it correct that $\underset{n\to\infty}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}=\limsup}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}$? 
i know its correct for regular $ \lim $  but im not sure for $ \limsup $. Also, is it correct that $ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{|a_{n+1}|}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}=\underset{n\to\infty}{\limsup}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|} $ ?

And how can I prove those claims? Thanks.

Comment: use that if $b_n \ge 0, b_n \to b, b_n^{\frac {n}{n \pm 1}} \to b$  (assuming $b_n \ne 0, n \ge n_0$ as otherwise $b=0$ and you can anyway discard the zero terms) take logarithms with the usual convention that $b_n \to 0$ iff $\log b_n \to -\infty$ etc (the cases $b=0, \infty$ are also easy to prove from the defintion by simple inequalities)

Comment: @conrad So you say that all of those claims are correct?

Comment: sure - same as in the usual limit c- another way of thinking is that those limsup's you want give the radius of convergence of the shifted power series which are essentially $zf(z)$ or $\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}$ and it is fairly intuitive that those operations don't change the radius of convergence

Comment: I guess the question is about non-convergent sequences $(|a_n|)^{1/n}$. If we assume convergence then $\limsup = \liminf = \lim$ which was already settled.

Comment: The way you wrote "$\underset{n\to\infty}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}=\limsup}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}$" with $n\to\infty$ in the middle seems rather unusual. Did you mean to write this: $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}$?